# git rebase three repositories

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I've got my local development branches (local/dev), the master branch of the original repository (origin/master) and my remote dev branch (remote/dev). When starting, local/dev and remote/dev are in sync.

Now I wanna fetch changes from origin/master, rebase it with my local/dev and push it to remote/dev.

So I've executed `git pull --rebase origin master` in my local/dev repository which seems to work fine.

But `git status` returns me this:

```
On branch dev
Your branch and 'remote/dev' have diverged,
and have 8 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and `git push remote dev` will result in

```
To github.com:PascalTurbo/dev.git
 ! [rejected]        logger -> logger (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:PascalTurbo/dev.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it’s not work fine when you execute `git pull --rebase origin master`. Let’s illustrate by below graphs (with two repositories-local and origin, this also used for three repositories):

```
  A---B---C  local/dev, origin/dev
 /         
D---E---F---G  origin/master
```

After `git pull --rebase origin master`

```
  A---B---C  origin/dev
 /         
D---E---F---G---A’---B’---C’  local/dev
            |
       origin/master
```

So it’s really diverged local/dev and remote/dev, and it’s not want you really want. 
There is a way for you to realize your requirement:

1. Recover local repo as remote.

`git fetch remote 
git reset --hard remote/dev
git pull origin`

2. Put origin/master changes on the top of local/dev branch.

`git checkout master 
git rebase dev 
git checkout dev 
git merge master`

3. Remove unused changes. `git branch –D master`
4. Push changes on local/dev branch to remote/dev.

`git checkout dev
git push remote dev`